# le function in matlab behaves in this weird fashion. why?

Tags: matlab

when entering the logical statement that says

```
le 4 5
```

MATLAB returns `1`. However if one does,

```
x=4;
```

and then

```
le x 5
```

MATLAB returns `0`. Why is this true and how can I successfully have MATLAB correctly evaluate whether expression is less than or equal to number?

Comment: Both `le(x,5)` and `x <= 5` work (and the latter is usual way to code logical statements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB has [2 function calling syntaxes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html), command and function.

Command syntax, used here, treats the inputs as character vectors. To make the logical comparison to a `double`, MATLAB implicitly converts `'x'` to a double, `120`, which is its ASCII equivalent. `le(120, 5)` will obviously evaluate `false`.

Use function syntax:

```
>> x = 4; le(x, 5)

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parenthesis as *le* is a function with arguments x and 5.
Typing: le(x,5) will return 1.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.